# Send data from a javascript ajax function to a jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, jsp

This is what I am trying to do. On a home page.. say /home.jsp, a user clicks on a link. I read value of the link and on the basis of which I call a RESTful resource which in turn manipulates database and returns a response. Interaction with REST as expected happens with use of JavaScript. I have been able to get information from REST resource but now I want to send that data to another JSP.. say /info.jsp. I am unable to do this.

I was trying to make another ajax call within success function of parent Ajax call but nothing is happening. For example:

```
function dealInfo(aparameter){



    var requestData = {
            "dataType":    "json",
            "type"    :    "GET",
            "url"     :    REST resource URL+aparameter,
    };

    var request = $.ajax(requestData);
    request.success(function(data){

        alert(something from data); //this is a success

        //I cannot get into the below AJAX call
        $.ajax({

            "type": "post",
            "url": "info.jsp"
            success: function(data){
                alert("here");
                ("#someDiv").html(data[0].deviceModel);
            }

        });
```

How do I go about achieving this? Should I use some other approach rather than two Ajax calls? Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following function:

```
function dealInfo(aparameter) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'thePage.jsp',
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {'aparameter': aparameter},
        success: function (data) {

            alert(data); //or you can use console.log(data);

            $.ajax({
                url: 'info.jsp',
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                data: {'oldValorFromFirstAjaxCall': data},
                success: function (info) {
                    alert(info); //or you can use console.log(info);
                    $("#someDiv").html(info);
                }
            });

        }
    });
}
```

Or make the AJAX call synchronous:

```
function dealInfo(aparameter) {
    var request = $.ajax({
        async: false, //It's very important
        cache: false,
        url: 'thePage.jsp',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {'aparameter': aparameter}
    }).responseText;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'info.jsp',
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data: {'oldValorFromFirstAjaxCall': request},
        success: function (info) {
            alert(info); //or you can use console.log(info);
            $("#someDiv").html(info);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this way I'm using.

"type": "post" instead of type: 'post'

---

Maybe it will help. Try it please. For Example;

```
$.ajax({
      url: "yourURL",
      type: 'GET',
      data: form_data,
      success: function (data) {
      ...
      }
});
```

Comment: Sorry it didn't work. It is not reaching the JSP I think.